# WSO2 API Manager always appends '*' to routes with trailing slashes

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager, swagger-ui

In WSO2 API Manager 2.1, whenever I attempt to create an endpoint with a trailing slash, e.g. `/countries/`, WSO2 appends a `*` to the route, e.g. `/countries/*`.  These are not recognized by the backend and thus, they fail.  If I look at the Swagger YAML, the route is correctly defined without the star, e.g. `/countries/`

How can I convince WSO2 API Manager to not add the `*` to my routes?

Here in **Publisher**, the route is defined as `/countries/`:
[image: Publisher view]

But in the published API, the route is presented as `/countries/*` and invocation of the route fails, seen here in the **Store's API Console**:
[image: Subscriber view]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Bee: Updated with screen shots.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a bug in the store console and is fixed in 2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue and is fixed in 2.2.0.

For 2.1.0, you can try fixing it yourself. Have a look at `swagger-ui.js` and `swagger-ui.min.js` files in

```
wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/api/swagger/swagger
```

---

See this.

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/3325/files